# logging two scripts in same file

Tags: python, logging

Sorry, it is a simple question, but I'm not understanding well what I have to do. There are two scripts: `main.py` and `methods.py`

`main.py`

```
import methods


methods.fnc_1()


methods.fnc_2()
```

`methods.py`

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

def fnc_1():
    logger.warning('warning_1!')

def fnc_2():
    logger.warning('warning_2!')
```

How can I use the same `logger` object in main.py? So, I call `main.py` and get every log message from either `main.py` or `methods.py` in the same file, shown at the order of execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `methods.logger` in `main.py` to get the variable from the `methods` module.

```
import methods

methods.fnc_1()
methods.logger.warning("warning from main!")
methods.fnc_2()
```